# Is there a way to intensify "blooming" in "The flowers are blooming"?

Tags: word-usage, intensifying-adverbs

In some languages, for example, in Korean, it is possible to intensify the act of blooming. For example, using the phrase 핍니다 would imply blooming, for example, simply "The flowers are blooming". However, it is possible to intensify this by using the phrase 많이 핍니다 which would mean something like "The flowers are blooming a lot". This however does not sound proper to me. Is there a way to intensify an abstract act like flower blooming (or any other), in English? For this particular example, are "The flowers are blooming a lot" or "The flowers are blooming very beautifully" proper ways to intensify the act of blooming?

Comment: I think the Korean phrase you've written down translates to "Lots of flowers are blooming."

Comment: I can think of another way to intensify it. Wildflowers are blooming abundantly in the garden.

Comment: There are many different ways of intensifying things in any language. ‘A lot’ is much more neutral than ‘beautifully’, which is adamantly positive. “The flowers are bloody blooming” would be going the other way, intensifying it in a negative light.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You're right that the modifier "a lot" sounds off. But "very beautifully" is fine. "A lot" can be replaced by "plentifully" or "abundantly" if you want quantity.

Adverbs modify verbs, just as adjectives modify nouns. *Are blooming* is the verb; *beautifully* is the adverb.

You can intensify the verb by intensifying the adverb:

- The flowers are blooming *nicely.*
- The flowers are blooming *attractively.*
- The flowers are blooming *beautifully.*
- The flowers are blooming *splendidly.*

Many adverbs can be formed from adjectives by adding -ly to the end.

pretty -> prettily
sweet -> sweetly
exquisite -> exquisitely

If you like an adjective, you may very well be able to use it as an adverb. You can place the adverb before or after the verb depending on the adverb, how it sounds, and what you're trying to emphasize.

Answer (score 2):

***in full bloom***

The idiom *in full bloom* literally means that all (most of) the flowers are fully open (blooming), presenting a delightful sight. *At this time of the year, the tulips are in full bloom*.

The expression is very widely used both in its literal as well as metaphorical sense.

> *The lilac bushes that formed the hedge were **in full bloom**, …* (Tolstoy)
>
> *She was a widow, but years ago had passed though her state of weeds, and burst into flower again; and **in full bloom** she had continued ever since; and **in full bloom** she was now; with roses on her ample skirts, … —ay, and roses, worth the gathering too, on her lips, for that matter*. (Dickens)

Answer (score 1):

You could put an adverb (like you did "beautifully") on the end of blooming. An adverb describes a verb, in this case describing how the flowers are blooming.

I think "The flowers are blooming beautifully" is a good way to put it. "blooming a lot" also works, but "a lot" is sort of a boring descriptor.

Answer (score 1):

A quite natural thing to say would be:

> The flowers are ***really*** blooming.

with the accent on *really*.

Answer (score 1):

*Blooming out*.

Using a verb intensifier like the word *out* places more emphasis on the verb. However, such intensifiers are **tricky** to use.

These would work:

- All the tickets to the concert were *sold out*.
- The flowers are *blooming out*.

Other examples would include *call out*, *cheat out*, and *help out*.

However, these would not work due to a change in meaning:

- I *read out* fifty pages from a book.
- When I exit the store, I *pull out* the door handle.

As well as numerous others like *move out*, *give out* and *eat out*.

Answer (score 1):

I really like what @SusanGerard suggests, especially the contrast of "abundantly" and "beautifully", which perhaps might be blended in together in Korean language.

In addition to that list, I would like to offer a few more words,

> The flowers are blooming *dazzlingly*.
>   The flowers are blooming *vividly*.
>   The flowers are blooming *vigorously*.

As for a way to intensify an abstract act like flower blooming (or any other), in English, I usually begin with either *intensely* or *extremely*, and find synonyms in my thesauruses.